# Internet Cafe launcher software with electron

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, electron

I am trying to figure out is it possible to make Internet Cafe client launcher with Electron. The app would have to prevent the user from ALT+TAB or CTRL+ALT+DEL it would also have to: run on startup, cover full screen, shut other processes down, run executable binaries and so on. I never before made application of this kind and do not know what kind of things am i looking for. First thing that i remember when using some other Internet Cafe clients is that they needed administrative rights, so i found [electron-sudo](https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo), but that is about it of what i know.

Comment: Chrome has a feature called [kiosk apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled) which can prevent the user from leaving, start at startup and cover the full screen. Shutting down proccesses is a bit more complicated. You will have to use external messaging to message another proccess which can handle the terminating and running of things.

Answer (score 1):

NW.js has Kiosk Mode.

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/the-kiosk-mode

It's similar to Electron but it runs a webpage first, not a script (if that makes sense). Basically, you get a browser that lets you run node.js.

And Kiosk mode.

Ah, so does Electron!

```
kiosk Boolean - The kiosk mode
```

I did not know that.